# Simulator shows my image in UIImageView but it doesn't on my real iPhone

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have looked around for the answer but it the answers I have found say that real devices are case sensitive and I've looked over my code and cannot find any problems,

I have 2 view controllers, `spViewController` which is my root and I have `secondViewController` which is self explanatory, there is an `UIImageView` in both to display the same image, which was picked from the gallery using `UIImagePickerController` in the simulator and real iPhone the image DOES display on the `spViewController's` `UIImageView` but on the `secondViewController` in the simulator the `UIImageView` DOES display the image but on the real iPhone the image DOES NOT display

**This code is in my `secondViewController.m`**

```
{NSString *docsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *filepathJPG = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"imagefile.jpg"];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: filepathJPG];
    if (img != nil) {

        _imageView.image = img;


        BOOL adjustToSmallSize = YES;
        CGRect smallSize = (CGRect){0,0,100,100};
        if (adjustToSmallSize) {
            _imageView.bounds = smallSize;
        }

    }
```

I have done a few tests of my own, I've been playing around with the file names and the caps and spellings, if i change the spellings of anything the image fails to load in the simulator also, if i keep it as `imagefile.jpg` then it loads in the simulator but not the real phone, I've played around with the caps and nothing seems to change on my iPhone or the simulator

Comment: why are you sure you're image is "imagefile.JPG"?

Comment: what does filepathJPG contains on runtime?

Comment: Try with @"**imagefile.jpg**". I had once faced the same issue with you where the simulator is NOT case sensitive but the on the real device, it is case sensitive.

Comment: i did put it as image file.jpg first i then changed it to see if i had made a mistake, i forgot to change it back before i posted it here

Comment: First check your spell is correct or wrong.
Remove image from bundle. add it again then check.

Comment: How about case like **Imagefile.jpg** vs. **imagefile.jpg**? Make sure  all the case for the file name is good.

Comment: i have tried all manner of combinations is it just the `@"imagefile.jpg"]` part that i should be looking at? I'm completely stumped on this

Comment: Yes, it is either your image name or the path of the image. I just added an answer below and I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix my problem i did the following

in my FVC.m

```
 -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    UIImage *chosenImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    //it returns the edited image

    NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    self.myImage = chosenImage;


    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage])
    {

        UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        _imageView.image = image;
        if (_newMedia)
        {

        }
        else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
        {

        }
    }

    [self performSelector:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:picker afterDelay:0.5];



}
```

and then this in my SVC.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _imageView.image = self.myImage;
```

hope this helps people in future

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `imagefile.JPG` is upper case JPG, or could be `imagefile.jpg`? Also check what `filepathJPG` string holds on run time when your `imageView` fails to load this image file.

Comment: sorry i changed those caps in JPG just to test, I'm a little confused what you mean by check what filepathJPG string holds on run? could you explain a little please or how do i do this?

Comment: just put it in `NSLog(@"File Path:----> %@",filepathJPG);` run this app on your device and check the log to see if actually this variable has a value when your `imageView` is failing to load image

Answer (score 0):

check your image name if it is ok than

delete DerivedData at /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/

and runs once again in the device.

Answer (score 0):

I just look back my old project and this is how I write the image to the **fullpath** and also get the image back from the **same path**:-

```
    if (self.photoView.image)
    {
        //Image file name
        NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"M%@.png", self.title];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docDir, filename];

        //Write the Image to the path
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.photoView.image);
        [imageData writeToFile:fullPath atomically:FALSE];

        //Get the image back from the same path
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
    }
```

I just realised that you forgot the **/** for the path. Please make sure that whenever you write or read the path, you have that. Can you try it out and let me know if it solves your problem?